# How to create properties dynamically?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to create properties dynamically.
My scenario is like this:
I have many classes that derive from BaseClass.
BaseClass has a dictionary where inherited classes should define stuff.  Those definitions are done like this.

```
public string Type 
{
    get 
    {
        return dictionary["type"];
    }
    set
    {
        dictionary["type"] = value;
    }
}
```

I will have many inherited methods like this in my derived classes, where the name of the property is almost identical to the key that references its corresponding value in the dictionary. So my idea is to add attributes in the derived classes, starting with an underscore, to distinguish them and use them to create those properties.

1. How would I define dynamically those properties at run-time?
2. Is it possible to define those at compile-time? Would it make sense to do so?

Comment: That look like a property to me, not a method :)

Comment: You're right... what a fail, correcting...

Comment: @E.Vaughan Properties are nothing more than methods. :)

Comment: @Erandros You can create methods dynamically, but do you _really_ want that?

Comment: A class derived from DynamicObject seems more appropriate

Comment: @Leri Hum... nice question, coming to the think of it, I'm not sure if I would save time by doing so.

Comment: How exactly would you access the properties, when they're defined only at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless am missing something. You can do something like this with `ExpandoObject`.

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Type = "123";//Create Type property dynamically
Console.WriteLine(obj.Type);//Access dynamically created Type property
```

Comment: The more interesting question, perhaps, is: is it *useful to the developer* to do this. In many cases, having indexer access is probably more relevent

Comment: @MarcGravell I've not used this in production code, No need for this till now. But I hope this is the answer for the question *How would I define dynamically those properties at run-time* As you said `indexer` is enough though.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - it is the best of the answers here (at time of writing); if anything, my thought there is aimed at the OP. What you have here *will work*

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, maybe it's unnecesary and I'll end up explicitly defining them. Nice answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions dynamically as follows,

```
Expression<Func<int, int, string>> exp = (x, y) => (x + y).ToString();
var func = exp.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(func.Invoke(2, 3));
```

Also you can put them in a dictionary and use them dynamically.

```
Expression<Func<int, int, string>> expSum = (x, y) => (x + y).ToString();
Expression<Func<int, int, string>> expMul = (x, y) => (x*y).ToString();
Expression<Func<int, int, string>> expSub = (x, y) => (x - y).ToString();

Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<int, int, string>>> myExpressions =
    new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<int, int, string>>>();

myExpressions.Add("summation", expSum);
myExpressions.Add("multiplication", expMul);
myExpressions.Add("subtraction", expSub);

foreach (var myExpression in myExpressions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myExpression.Value.Compile().Invoke(2, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build those at compile-time under the hood (no C# behind it), see [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) (it allows you to define custom patterns)

But to "create" new functions, you may be interested in:

- [Expression.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create delegates (dynamic methods, which are garbage collectible in .net 4.5)
  Pros: that's still C#. Cons: That does not allow creating types.
- [Reflection.Emit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec) (in .Net framework) or [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) (thirdparty) if you want to emit dynamic types or methods at runtime.
  Using this, a solution to your question would be to define your properties as abstract, and dynamically create a type (at runtime) which inherits from you abstract class defined in C#, an implements it automatically.
  Pros: VERY powerfull. Cons: You have to learn IL :)